# java program to Connect remote machine and execute batch file through WinRm

Tags: java, batch-file, winrm

1)I partially connected to remote machine and use WinRm through Java to execute .bat file using  xebialabs.overthere jars, which got rejected due to licence issue.

2) I even tried to connect remote machine and run batch file through PSExec (without using WinRm), but due to constraints of installing PSExec to our Master machine, this solution was scrapped.

Please help me if there is any way to get this done.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Check line 37 of your code. Just kidding...obviously without seeing your code I can't tell you where your bug is. :) What I can tell you is that you should be able to use WinRS to run the batch file remotely. I've never tried calling a cmd shell from Java (not sure why you would want to run Java to run cmd to run winrs to run a remote batch file) though.

Comment: Basically I want to connect to a remote machine and execute a batch/exe files. I tried it through Java by above two ways which is running good,Since the above two ways has its own constraints  I need any alternative way to do it using Java and WinRM.